# Can't figure out why syntax error near "from" is appearing for sqldf in R

Tags: sql, r, syntax-error, sqldf

I'm trying to compare subject IDs between columns to find unique IDs. I keep on getting a syntax error even though I've spent the past hour checking and re-checking my syntax. I decided to make a simple data frame to play around with an low and behold I get the same error.

Here my syntax for the proxy data frame

```
color <- c('yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue') 
number <- c(1,3,4,5) 
stuff <- data.frame(color, number) 

sqldf('select number, from stuff where color = red')
```

Here's the error I got

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : error in
>   statement: near "from": syntax error

I'm beyond frustrated that I can't get this simple query to work. What gives?
I even tried removing the comma before 'from' and then I get the following error.

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :    error in
>   statement: no such column: red

Comment: a comma after number `,` in the query

Comment: tried removing that and I got the second error about no column called red existing, which is true.  but that shouldn't matter since i explicitly stated I wanted it to look in the column 'color'

Comment: surround either side of red with quotes. I did not see that before. `'red'`

Comment: You didn't put `red` in quotes. Use double quotes for the query, single quotes for things in the query that need to be quoted.

Comment: Since it's clear you don't understand SQL that well, why don't you use base R subsetting and whatnot?

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked.  And @cory that probably would have made more sense.  I just got started down this road thinking it would be quicker and wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove commas and change quotes:

```
> stuff
   color number
1 yellow      1
2    red      3
3  green      4
4   blue      5

> sqldf("select number from stuff where color = 'red'")
  number
1      3
```